# Android Custom Listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have some boring question. I am beginner of android. I am trying to make Custom Listview. I can not understand this code.

Why use `ArrayAdapter<ItemList>` and why pass value `super(context, R.layout.activity_custom_adapter)`?

Why use `getView()` and why use layout again `R.layout.activity_custom_adapter`?

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemList> {

    ArrayList<ItemList> item;
    Activity context;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<ItemList> item) {
       super(context, R.layout.activity_custom_adapter, item);
       this.item=item;
       this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view=convertView;
        if(view==null){
            LayoutInflater inflate=context.getLayoutInflater();
            view=inflate.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_adapter, parent, false);

        }

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: this will answer most of your questions http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why use `ArrayAdapter<ItemList>`?

This means that your `CustomAdapter` is a subclass of `ArrayAdapter`, and that it will contain classes only of type `ItemList`. All `ListViews` need an adapter of some sort to translate plain Java classes into `Views` that the `ListView` can use as rows in the list.

If you aren't sure what subclasses are or how inheritance works, I highly recommend the [What is Inheritance?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html) page from the Java tutorials.

> Why pass value super(context, R.layout.activity_custom_adapter)?

The `ArrayAdapter` class does a lot of work for you when it comes to creating an adapter for a `ListView`. This line calls the constructor for `ArrayAdapter` to ensure that all of that class' member variables are initialized properly. Again, I would check out the guide to inheritance that I linked to above.

> Why use getView()?

`getView()` is a method defined in the root [`Adapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) class. The `@Override` annotation  means that we don't want to use the default `getView()` implementation provided by any super classes.

Remember that an adapter is responsible for converting plain Java objects into `View` instances for the list. Whenever the `ListView` needs to generate a `View` for another row in the list, it will call `getView()`.

> Why use layout again `R.layout.activity_custom_adapter`?

This layout is the layout for each individual row in the list. `getView()` will return a copy of this layout for each item in the list.

Comment: when use super(context, R.layout.activity_custom_adapter) then is it doing pass value or called arrayAdapter construcor?

Comment: when i pass other layout then it did not change super??(context, R.layout.customlistactivity_layout, books);

Comment: When you call `super(context, R.layout.activity_custom_adapter)`, you are calling one of `ArrayAdapter's` constructors and passing in your context and layout values.

Comment: Since the example overrides `getView()`, you need to change the row layout there instead of using the constructor. The row layout is the first argument to `inflate()`.

Comment: I'm going to have to pass on that one. You are welcome to ask more questions here on StackOverflow though!

Comment: when call construcotr CustomAdapter(, , ,) then this class return getview value view??

Comment: When you call the constructor for `CustomAdapter`, you get an instance of the `CustomAdapter` class. You shouldn't be calling `getView()` yourself but if you were to call `getView()` then you would get an instance of the View that you inflate.

Comment: i did not call getView,,                                       adapter=new CustomAdapter(this, getAllBooks());
lv.setAdapter(adapter);                                               may be  listview call this getview ... THanks bro...